# Android : how Custom Dialog returns intent result to parent activity

Tags: android, android-intent, customdialog, onactivityresult

In my `mainactivity` class, on clicking a button, it displays a dialog that shows, "capture a photo", "capture a video", pick from gallery" buttons upon clicking any of those button it has to  do the respective action and return the path of file to `mainactivity`.
It is easy to do with `startActivityForResult&onActivityResult` within `mainactivity`.
But how can I use intent with in custom dialog and return the intent result from custom dialog to `mainactivity`.

Thanks for your time.

```
takeaPhoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, ACTION_TAKE_PHOTO);
    }
});

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { 
    switch(){
        //do action
        String filePath = data.getDataString();
        filename.setText(filePath);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not tough. Just use alert Dialog and make sure that your views are right.

```
final Context context = this;
static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 1; 

takeaphoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v){  

LayoutInflater myLayout = LayoutInflater.from(context);
final View dialogView = myLayout.inflate(R.layout.YOURCUSTOM.XML, null);
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
alertDialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);
final AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();        


Button button1 = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
public void onClick(View v) {


Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_PICTURE);
}});

alertDialog.show();
return;}});
```